# Error when bulk inserting in r using dbBulkCopy

Tags: r, rclr

I have tried every alternative but I have no other options for doing what I want (bulk insert in r using dbBulkCopy), I am getting this error:

`install.packages(pkg='C:/folder/rClr_0.7-2.zip') inferring 'repos = NULL'`

> from 'pkgs' package 'rClr' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
>
> library(rClr) Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rClr', details:   call: fun(libname, pkgname)   error: 'msvcr120.dll' was not
>   found on this Windows system. You are probably missing the Visual C++
>   Redistributable for Visual Studio 2013. Check instructions at
>   https://r2clr.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Installing%20R%20packages&referringTitle=Documentation
>   In addition: Warning message: package 'rClr' was built under R version
>   3.1.2  Error: package or namespace load failed for 'rClr'

Comment: This question seems to have a terrible title, your issue seems to be that you can't load the rClr package, and specifically because you don't have the C++ runtime installed.  Do you?

Comment: I have It, and I have double checked visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2013 too.

Comment: And I yes, I know I did something beyond terrible. Since I am new here at any tech forum.

Comment: @Eqra since you are new please consider taking the [tour] and having a look at [ask]. This will help you understand how SO works.

Comment: Alright. Can't you guys answer me without editing?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you don't have 'msvcr120.dll' available.  You can confirm this by verifying the following is true:

```
Sys.which('msvcr120.dll') == ''
```

As to why it isn't available, you should start by comparing the path that you believe it is installed in to what is returned by `Sys.getenv()`

Answer (score 0):

After few hours of research I got what the issue was, and here I want to share how I resolved it.

install requited packages 
1- install Rtools on your system
2- then devtools
3- then rsqlserver
4- then rClr

```
install.packages("devtools.zip", repos = NULL, type = "source")
install_github("jmp75/rClr", build_vignettes=TRUE)
install_github('agstudy/rsqlserver')
library(devtools)
library(rClr)
library(rsqlserver)
dat22 <- data.frame(TFN = c('300', '300', '300', '300'), ID = c(1:4), HOUR = c(1, 1, 2,5))    
urlLocal = "Data Source=111.00.10.10; Initial Catalog=bo; Integrated Security=False;Persist Security Info=True; User   Id=yourname;Password=yourpass;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
conLocal <- dbConnect('SqlServer', url = urlLocal)
```